# SSO - Multple SP with only one IdP (ADFS)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs, service-provider, idp

I have two service providers set up with one IdP and users are required to be authenticated twice to access both services at the same time. From my point of view, this is not "SSO" and I am thinking that there might have been settings done incorrectly and I would like to see if the community here can provide me with directions and/or possible solutions.

Just a thought - the behaviour for the authentication on each service looks valid as I understand that IdP is required to send signed SAML assertions to the providers in order to access the services. However, because I only have one IdP, can I not be authenticated just once and be able to access all the services?

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in this scenario the user would authenticate once to the IdP when the first SP SSO's to it. There would be no authentication at the IdP when the second SP SSO's to it as there's already an authentication session at the IdP for the user.

However, there might be use cases where you want the user to be authenticated at the IdP even if they already have an authentication session. The SP can set the ForceAuthn flag in the SAML authn request sent to the IdP. This requests that the IdP authenticates the user regardless of whether or not they already have an authentication session.

ADFS also has a configuration option for relying parties (SPs) to always require authentication. Take a look at the AlwaysRequireAuthentication flag.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/set-adfsrelyingpartytrust?view=windowsserver2022-ps